# Postgresql case statement returns empty row when condition is not met

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following statement in a `query`:

```
CASE 
  WHEN "PI".statusid_dec = 'Entered' 
   and "PI".pagename = 'Procedural Information' 
   and "PI".pishact IS NULL 
   then 'ACT (Activated Clotting time)' 
END
```

The issue is, that if there are records where `"PI".pagename is NOT 'Procedural Information'`, I get an extra (blank) row for these cases. How can I modify this query so that I only get a row for every time the `'case when'` statement matches exactly?

Complete query:

```
SELECT

DISTINCT "DAT_SUB".SUBNUM as "Subject ID",

CONCAT_WS(',',

CASE WHEN "DM".statusid_dec = 'Entered' and "DM".sex IS NULL then 'Gender' 
END,
CASE WHEN "DM".statusid_dec = 'Entered' and "DM".brthyr IS NULL then 'Year 
of 
Birth' END,
CASE WHEN "DM".statusid_dec = 'Entered' and "DM".icdat IS NULL then 
'Informed 
consent date' END) as "Demographics",

CASE WHEN "PI".statusid_dec = 'Entered' and "PI".pagename = 'Procedural 
Information' and "PI".pishact IS NULL then 'ACT (Activated Clotting time)' 
END 
as "Procedure"

FROM "Disco_Radial"."DAT_SUB"
//These are all the tables I want to add similar case-statements for. They 
are currently not being used yet, because I wanted to solve this issue 
above first. 

LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."ACM" ON "Disco_Radial"."ACM".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."AE" ON "Disco_Radial"."AE".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."CH" ON "Disco_Radial"."CH".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."CL" ON "Disco_Radial"."CL".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."CRF" ON "Disco_Radial"."CRF".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."DIS" ON "Disco_Radial"."DIS".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."DM" ON "Disco_Radial"."DM".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."IE" ON "Disco_Radial"."IE".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."LB" ON "Disco_Radial"."LB".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."PA" ON "Disco_Radial"."PA".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."PE" ON "Disco_Radial"."PE".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."PI" ON "Disco_Radial"."PI".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."SE" ON "Disco_Radial"."SE".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."SS" ON "Disco_Radial"."SS".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."VS" ON "Disco_Radial"."VS".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."DAT_RAND" ON "Disco_Radial"."DAT_RAND".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM
LEFT JOIN "Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS" ON "Disco_Radial"."DAT_PAGS".SUBNUM = 
"DAT_SUB".SUBNUM

ORDER BY "DAT_SUB".subnum;
```

The output looks like this:

"DR-05-001";"";"ACT (Activated Clotting time)"
"DR-05-001";"";""
"DR-05-002";"";"ACT (Activated Clotting time)"
"DR-05-003";"";"ACT (Activated Clotting time)"
"DR-05-004";"";"ACT (Activated Clotting time)"
"DR-05-005";"";"ACT (Activated Clotting time)"
"DR-05-006";"";"ACT (Activated Clotting time)"

...

The issue is for records like DR-05-001, which has rows in the "PI" table that don't have pagename 'Procedural Information'.

Comment: It would be better with the whole query

Comment: @Zegher V changing the requirement invalidates the answers that you already get. You should have posted a new question where you could explain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A `case` expression just specifies the value to return per row. If you want to exclude some rows, you'll need to add a `where` clause with that logic.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to add similar statements from other tables? Is there a way to make the where-clause apply to only one output column?

Comment: @ZegherV not sure I understand your comment. A `where` clause filters out entire rows, not columns

Comment: Yes, and a where clause would work fine in the current query, but my aim is to create similar case statements but from other tables, that do not have the same columns as this one. So that is why I cannot use the where clause right now. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, and a where clause would work fine in the current query, but my aim is to create similar case statements but from other tables, that do not have the same columns as this one. So that is why I cannot use the where clause right now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add `WHERE "PI".pagename = 'Procedural Information'` to your query and you can remove it from the CASE expression:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN "PI".statusid_dec = 'Entered' and "PI".pishact IS NULL 
    THEN 'ACT (Activated Clotting time)' 
  END
FROM "PI"
WHERE "PI".pagename = 'Procedural Information'
```

Note that if the condition:

```
"PI".statusid_dec = 'Entered' and "PI".pishact IS NULL
```

is not `TRUE` for any row you will still get empty rows in the results.

Comment: Yes that would be the solution if this was the only column I wanted to create in this report, but I want to have other columns from other tables than "PI". I edited my post to have the complete query!

Comment: This code answers the question as you posted it. If you have another requirement then you can post a new question about it.